# Why not serialize abstract classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop, serialization, abstract-class

I have read that generally abstract classes should not be made Serializable in Java. The subclasses should be serializable (with custom read, write methods if required, for eg. when abstract classes have fields).

What is the reason behind this? Why is it considered bad design?

**Update1:** I have an abstract class with some fields and three subclasses. As of now, I am using the following approach.

I have made all the subclasses serializable with custom read, write methods. In the abstract class I have the following methods.

```
void writeFields(ObjectOutputStream out)throws IOException { .... }

void readFields(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{ ... }
```

In the custom read, write methods in the subclasses I call these methods to (de) serialize the fields in the abstract class. Is this approach correct? Or is there a different better approach?

**Update 2:** I took Tom's advice and made my abstract class Serializable. (I want all subclasses to be Serializable and I have data in the abstract class) This is an aside, but just to complete the story I am using [reflection to change final fields as advised by Jeremy Manson.](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-3.html)

Comment: This question applies to ANY object oriented language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know that it is necessarily bad design. Serialisation is effectively an implementation issue (note, Josh Bloch disagrees with me), so doesn't make sense for interfaces. If the abstract class has state, then you would want to make it serialisable. If it doesn't have state, there isn't really any reason to make it so.

Let's take an example. `java.security.cert.Certificate` is an abstract serialisable class, with a `"type"` serialisable field. If it wasn't serialisable it would not be possible for a subclass to be serialisable and set that field. You would be forced in to a hack.

Note that `java.io.Serializable` is a hack. It shouldn't have been an interface. An annotation (or language evolution like `transient`) would have been more appropriate.

As always, it's best to prefer composition to inheritance and not to make random class serialisable.

Comment: @athena You really don't want methods like that in an API.

Comment: Why not? I want all subclasses to be Serializable. The abstract class has fields. In this situation, is it better to make the abstract class Serializable(with custom read write methods)?

Comment: @athena I suggest making the base class serialisable, whether accepting the default serial form or providing another. Adding methods that allow other classes to read and write fields is going to be bad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the methods might cause problems.

Answer (score 10):

I think the reason is that if an Abstract class implements Serializable, there is no way to say that a sub type should NOT be Serializable.  Better to let each concrete type declare for itself...

Comment: I want all subclasses to be Serializable. The abstract class has fields. In this situation, is it better to make the abstract class Serializable?

Comment: looking at the collection framework - no ;) AbstractList is not serializable. But it is not such a great difference anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take the oposite position. If you were to De-Serialize the object, what would be its type?

By definition, an abstract class can't be instantiated. If you can serialize it, that implies that it can also be deserialized and that would get you an instance of the abstract class. That contradicts the definition of an abstract class and therefore can't be done.

Comment: +1, was about to say the same thing a bit differently, but your answer illustrates it much more succinctly than I what I would have said.

Comment: If you deserialised the object, it's class would be the same as the object that was serialised (give or take `writeReplace`/`readResolve`).

Comment: I believe your argument is flawed.  It is not possible to instantiate an abstract class.  Therefore, it is never possible that you need to de-serialize an astract class.  Any de-serialization of an abstract class will be in the context of a derived concrete class which means, the class is known at the point of de-serialization.

Comment: @Tom, @dwb, I agree with your statements. And in these scenarios, the derived class would need to be serialized, not the base class.

Comment: @Babak Naffas No the base class really does need to be serialised if it contains data.

Comment: Implementing Serializable in the base class just says that all its subclasses must be serializable too. I think it's just a part of contract and can be even applied to interfaces. So I don't get it too why it's bad (or is it?).

Answer (score 1):

It's only bad design because it's a forced decision, what if you want a subclass that has non-serializable members.

That's why.

E.g. List is not Serializable, but every major list implementation is. (I know list is a Interface, but a abstract class with no members =/= a interface)

Answer (score 0):

If `abstract` class contains important for serialization fields and you are not going to implement custom object reader/writer it is *essential to declare that base class as `Serializable`*.

Declaring base class (or interface) as `Serializable` makes all sub-classes `Serializable` including any transitive path.

Latter makes sense if you implement some framework: you ease life your users automatically propagating interface, otherwise you should document that you work with `Serializable` only or implement runtime checks for user supplied classes.

I added base class for entities (to unify naming standard, for fields like `id`, `createdDate`, `updatedDate`) and forgot to mark it as `Serializable`. As a result any Entity kept in session store (Redis) had `null` `id` values upon deserialization )) You don't want this.

**UPDATE** `Serializable` requires public no-arg constructor for deserialization. Declaration of inheritance doesn't create no-arg constructor for sub-classes nor for super-class, it's a users' chore. Superclass without default constructor breaks deserialization for all sub-classes ))

**UPDATE 2** There is a way to declare that subclass is not designed for serialization even if it is inherited from base class that is `Serialazable` although it is runtime feature:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
{ throw new NotSerializableException(); }
  
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException
{ throw new NotSerializableException(); }
```