# Abstract class with gwt and serializable?

Tags: java, class, serialization, gwt, interface

Goodmorning guy,

i got many problems with english (:D) and GWT.

In GWT, abstract class can be serialazable?

This is my code for project about ElectionOnline. Thx u very much for ur help.

```js
package elezione.eco.shared;

public abstract class User 
{
 protected String username;
 protected String password;
 protected String email;
 protected String name;
 protected String surname;
 protected String sex;
 protected String birthDate;
 protected String birthPlace;
 protected String address;
 
 public User(){}
 
 
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public String getSurname() {
  return surname;
 }

 public String getSex() {
  return sex;
 }

 public String getBirthDate() {
  return birthDate;
 }

 public String getBirthPlace() {
  return birthPlace;
 }

 public String getAddress() {
  return address;
 }

 public String getUsername(){
  return username;
 }
 
 public String getPassword(){
  return password;
 }
 
 public String getEmail(){
  return email;
 } 

}
```

```js
package elezione.eco.server;

import elezione.eco.client.ECOService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import elezione.eco.shared.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.mapdb.DB;
import org.mapdb.DBMaker;

/**
 * The server-side implementation of the RPC service.
 */
public class ECOServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ECOService {
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 LoginServiceImpl loginService;
 
 public ECOServiceImpl() {
  DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB( new File( "ECO-DB.txt" ) ).closeOnJvmShutdown().make();

  loginService = new LoginServiceImpl( db );
 }
 
 public void restartDb() {
  loginService.clear();  
  loginService.addAdmin();
 }
 
 public void populate() {

  try {
   addUser( "Sergio" , "m" , "sergio@studio.it" , null , null , null , null , null , null );
  } catch ( DuplicatedUserNameException e ) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 public User addUser( String username, String password, String email, String name, String surname, String sex,
   String birthDate, String birthPlace, String address ) throws DuplicatedUserNameException {
  return loginService.addUser( username , password , email , name , surname , sex , birthDate , birthPlace ,
    address );
 }

 public User login( String userName, String password ) throws WrongPasswordException, UserNotFoundException {
  return loginService.login( userName , password );
 }
 
 public ArrayList<User> getRegistered() {
  return loginService.getRegistered();
 }
 
 public ArrayList<User> getAllUsers() {
  return loginService.getAllUsers();
 }
}
```

Ok i don't understand because gwt compile error with serializable. A class abstract can be serializable? i have to implement pattern abstract. Thx

Comment: You can not create instance of an abstract class. you have to provide Child class for the abstract class so that GWT service can create instance and serialized it

Comment: Possible duplicate of this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452941/why-not-serialize-abstract-classes-in-java

Answer (score 1):

GWT (GWT-RPC to be specific) support serialize a IsSerializable class who extends abstract serializable class.

If you are looking for a DTO class without specific implementation on the client side, you are looking for `Proxy` or `RequestFactory`

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html